# How to run PING command and get ping host summary in C#?

Tags: c#, console, ping

I need to execute a PING command using C# code and get a summary of the ping host.

I need to send 8 packets, will display 8 echo replies in my command promt with statistics.

How to do it in C# console application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this example:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo( @"cmd.exe", "/c ping -n 8 google.com" )
{
     CreateNoWindow = true,
     UseShellExecute = false,
     RedirectStandardOutput = true
};

var pingProc = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
pingProc.Start();

pingProc.WaitForExit();

var result = pingProc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine( result );
Console.ReadKey();
```

If you need know about ping result here example:

```
...
pingProc.WaitForExit();

var reader = pingProc.StandardOutput;
var regex = new Regex( @".+?\s+=\s+(\d+)(,|$)" );

var sent = 0;
var recieved = 0;
var lost = 0;

string result;
while ( ( result = reader.ReadLine() ) != null )
{
    if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty( result ) )
       continue;

    var match = regex.Matches( result );
    if ( match.Count != 3 )
       continue;

    sent = Int32.Parse( match[0].Groups[1].Value );
    recieved = Int32.Parse( match[1].Groups[1].Value );
    lost = Int32.Parse( match[2].Groups[1].Value );
}

var success = sent > 0 && sent == recieved && lost == 0;
```

Comment: throws an exception " access denied"

Comment: @VenkateswaraReddy Change `google.com` to your host address.

Comment: No change in exception same like before.Shows as 'access denied'

Comment: @VenkateswaraReddy looks like you have some strict system policy or some kind of antivirus (firewall), try ping from command line manually

Comment: @VenkateswaraReddy please, share exception message with detail and line number where it throw. And try execute manually full command `cmd.exe /c ping -n 8 your_host`

Comment: at pingProc.start() and the exception is System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception {"Access is denied"}

Comment: yeah its working but i need to show error message if timed out or any packet loss.How can i achieve that? @Dmitry

Comment: @VenkateswaraReddy You could parse response text to get information about errors.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this example in MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb7xxkfx(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public static void RemotePing ()
{
    // Ping's the local machine.
    Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
    IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1"); //or IP address you'd like
    PingReply reply = pingSender.Send (address);

    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString ());
        Console.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
        Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
        Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
        Console.WriteLine ("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine (reply.Status);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question - He wants to ping a remote host.

Comment: OK. Let's change the 2nd row to:

IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(yourREMOTE_IPAddress);

Comment: @PalBognar ur answer is absolutely right but i need to show echo replies as well as statistics but i ur answer shows only statistics.That is the probelm

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new `Process` with the `cmd.exe x.x.x.x -n 8` as the file argument and the `ping` as the command argument.

Then, you can read its result data using a `StreamReader` which reads the process' `StandardOutput`:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -n 8";
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.Start();

StreamReader reader;
reader = proc.StandardOutput;
proc.WaitForExit();

reader = proc.StandardOutput;
string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Please remember to include: `using System.Diagnostics;`

**The output** should be:

```
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms

Ping statistics for ::1:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: i need to sent 4 packets and will receive 8 packets otherwise it will show an error message like "ping unsuccessful"

Comment: Use `-n 8` arguments of `ping` command to change packet size.

Comment: @Dmitry Thank you for your comment. Very helpful.

Comment: Be careful with your terms. Packet size can easily be misunderstood as packet length (l). n is the packet count.

Comment: but it throws an error "base = {"StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet."} " like this..so what i do?

Comment: Add `proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;`@VenkateswaraReddy

Comment: @KobyDouek again throws exception {"The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams."}

Comment: @KobyDouek set this in `ProcessStartInfo` struct: `CreateNoWindow = true, UseShellExecute = false, RedirectStandardOutput = true`. And use `/c` argument of `cmd.exe` to terminate after ping.

Comment: Add `proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;` @VenkateswaraReddy

Comment: @VenkateswaraReddy What is the exception?

Comment: {"The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams."} @KobyDouek

Comment: Set `proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;` @VenkateswaraReddy

Comment: throws an exception access denied @KobyDouek

Comment: @VenkateswaraReddy What is the exact message?

Comment: "access denied"

Comment: @VenkateswaraReddy At what code line do you get it? Paste it here.

Comment: at proc.start() {"Access is denied"}

Comment: have you entered a correct path to cmd.exe? can you try running this program as an administrator?