# How to run automatically a command in the CMD after starting it as a process (using C#)

Tags: c#, .net-core, cmd, ping

I'm trying to develop a ping tester program, and I'd love to add the chance to ping an IP adress by using the CMD, but the user should not write the command, as it should just start by itself and do the ping and display the usual information.

By far this is my code:

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

process.StartInfo.Arguments = "ping " + element.Ip;   //not working

process.Start();

process.WaitForExit();
```

If anyone can help me I would be really grateful .

Comment: Any reason why you are not using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=net-8.0 ?

Comment: Explain what "not working" really means. Is there an error? Is the behavior not what you expect? What types are `element` and `element.Ip`? Why not start `ping` directly and not worry about `cmd`? Consider putting together a [mcve].

Comment: See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540375/how-to-run-ping-command-and-get-ping-host-summary-in-c

Comment: @RickDavin I am also using Ping class but to send just a normal ping, i don't know if I have to use that class also to send a Ping by the CMD

Comment: @RetiredNinja sorry, it is my first time using this platform.
So, the "not working" means that my program just start the CMD process and then it doesnt do anything else. I wanted the process to send a ping to the IP contained in my element.cs class. I achieve that ip by selecting it from a datagrid, but that part is working fine, it is just the CMD that is giving me troubles.

Comment: `ping` is with its fully qualified file name `%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe`. Executables like `ping.exe` or `cmd.exe` are started on Windows by calling the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with appropriate function parameters and an appropriate filled out [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure.

Comment: It makes not difference for `CreateProcess` if a C# coded executable or `cmd.exe` calls `CreateProcess` for the execution of `ping.exe` in the (operating) system directory of Windows. The C# [Process Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) calls also `CreateProcess` with a `STARTUPINFO` structure. Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) and run what you try to execute from within the C# coded application: `cmd.exe ping 127.0.0.1`

Comment: All you get output is the version of Microsoft Windows (as stored in `cmd.exe`) and the copyright information. There is no output by `ping.exe`. Why? The *Windows Command Processor* was not instructed to run `ping.exe` with `127.0.0.1` as argument. Therefore the currently running `cmd.exe` started on opening the command prompt window just started a second instance of `cmd.exe` which keeps running until the user executes the command `exit` which you should do now to close the second `cmd.exe`. The command prompt window of first `cmd.exe` remains open for next command execution.

Comment: Run now `cmd /?`. That outputs the usage help of the *Windows Command Processor*. There are explained the options supported by `cmd.exe`. It is necessary to run `cmd.exe` with either `/C` or `/K` as last option for the execution of a command line by `cmd.exe`. The help explains also how the argument(s) after option `/C` (run command line and when finished __close__) or option `/K` (run command line and when finished __keep__ running) is interpreted by `cmd.exe` depending on several criteria. The execution of `cmd /C ping 127.0.0.1` does more as it can be seen on running this command.

Comment: The running `cmd.exe` started on opening the command prompt window searches for a file with name `cmd` as described in full details in my answer on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) It finds (hopefully) first `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` and calls now `CreateProcess` with that string as application name (`lpApplicationName`) and the string `/C ping 127.0.0.1` as command line (`lpCommandLine` – arguments for the application).

Comment: The started `cmd.exe` interprets the arguments, detects the option `/C` and interprets therefore the other arguments as command line to process and finally execute. The `cmd.exe` instance started on opening the command prompt window waits in the meantime for the self-termination of the started executable `cmd.exe`. The second `cmd.exe` searches now for a file with name `ping` and (hopefully) finds `C:\Windows\System32\ping.exe`. It calls `CreateProcess` for running this executable with `lpApplicationName` pointing to the string `C:\Windows\System32\ping.exe` and `lpCommandLine` pointing to

Comment: the string `127.0.0.1` and waits for self-termination of started `ping.exe`. The Windows console application `ping.exe` uses now several Windows library functions to send ICMP ECHO requests to local host and processes the replies with printing the output to `stdout` handle passed from first `cmd.exe` to second `cmd.exe` and further to `ping.exe`. Then `ping.exe` exits itself. The second `cmd.exe` gets notified about the self-termination of `ping.exe` with its exit code and closes/exits itself with the exit code returned by `ping.exe` to second `cmd.exe`.

Comment: The first `cmd.exe` gets notified about the self-termination of second `cmd.exe` with the exit code and assigns the exit code to its internal variable ´ERRORLEVEL` and keeps running. Then first `cmd.exe` becomes again responsive for user input from `stdin` (keyboard in this case). Now you have learned how a process can run another executable. Do you really think the execution of `cmd.exe` from within the C# coded application by calling `CreateProcess` makes sense just for running `ping.exe` by `cmd.exe` with calling also `CreateProcess`? I hope the answer is: no!

Comment: See the Microsoft documentations [Environment.SpecialFolder Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder) and [Environment.SystemDirectory Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.systemdirectory) and use `process.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.SystemDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "ping.exe";` and `process.StartInfo.Arguments = "ping " + element.Ip;`. __But is it really necessary for a C# coded application running `ping.exe`? No, it isn't.__

Comment: `ping.exe` just uses functions for sending ICMP ECHO requests to a device on the network and process the replies if the other device is reachable on the network at all, accepts the ICMP ECHO requests and replies accordingly. The other device could also ignore the ICMP ECHO requests completely or just for the specific sender. Which functions? `GetIpErrorString`, `GetIpForwardTable`, `Icmp6CreateFile`, `Icmp6SendEcho2`, `IcmpCloseHandle`, `IcmpCreateFile`, `IcmpSendEcho2Ex`, `InternalIcmpCreateFileEx`, `SetCurrentThreadCompartmentId` from `%SystemRoot%\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL`.

Comment: Microsoft made it easy for C# programmers to use ICMP ECHO requests for checking the availability of a device on a network and willing to reply to the requests by offering the [Ping Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping) and explaining its usage with examples. So, what was your mistake at the beginning of your development? You skipped the research phase and started directly with the implementation phase or have not spent enough time and efforts on the research how the code could be written to achieve the goal according to the requirements.